# Setting up a cookie-less domain for static assets

Tags: http, cookies, subdomain, assets

I have a web app that makes use of a couple cookies that each have the domain property:
".vibecompass.com"

The cookies are shared across several sub-domains (de.vibe.... & es.vibe... etc.)

I'm loading all my static assets from this subdomain: "www.vibecompass.com"
I do this essentially because I'm using cloudflare to auto-minify and gzip (plus act as a CDN) my js & css files. But of course, my session cookies are being sent with every request which is inefficient.

Will a cookie that has the following domain:
".vibecompass.com"

be sent by a browser for http requests to:
"staticassets.www.vibecompass.com"

This would be a lot more convenient that using a different TLD in my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path), the domain attribute of a cookie applies to its subdomains as well, so `'.vibecompass.com'` will apply to "**www**.vibecompass.com" as well as "**staticassets.www**.vibecompass.com".

I know you said you don't have the option of a new top-level domain, but can you set up "**static**.vibecompass.com" for the static content? Then you can apply your cookies only to the "**www**.vibecompass.com" subdomain.

If that's not an option, you can try using the path field. You'll have to have all the dynamic content (webpages) in their own directory like "www.vibecompass.com/**site**/", then you can have your cookies apply to that directory only (domain: `'www.vibecompass.com'`, path: `'/site'`).